# Помогите реализовать @DeleteMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Есть сущность Document

```
package ru.hiik.documentsite.models;


import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Document {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String title;
    @Column
    private String body;


}
```

Есть контроллер

```
package ru.hiik.documentsite.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import ru.hiik.documentsite.dao.DocumentRepo;
import ru.hiik.documentsite.models.Document;

import java.util.Optional;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("documents")
public class DocumentController {

    @Autowired
    DocumentRepo documentRepo;

    @GetMapping
    public String getAllDocuments(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("documents", documentRepo.findAll());
        return "document-page";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/create")
    public String createDocuments(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("document", new Document());
        return "create";
    }

    @PostMapping("/create/submit")
    public String submitDocument(@ModelAttribute Document document){
        documentRepo.save(document);
        return "redirect:../";
    }

    @DeleteMapping
    public void deleteDocument(){

    }
}
```

Есть репозиторий, подключена база Postgres

```
package ru.hiik.documentsite.dao;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import ru.hiik.documentsite.models.Document;

public interface DocumentRepo extends CrudRepository<Document, Integer> {

}
```

И есть шаблон Thymeleaf

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome to DocServer</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/documents/create">Создать документ<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/documents">Список документации</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>


<div class="main">
    <div th:each="document:${documents}">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title" th:text="${document.title}"/>
                <p class="card-text" th:text="${document.body}"/>
                <button>Удалить</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Помогите реализовать @DeleteMapping в контроллере и повесить на кнопку "удалить" в шаблоне этот метод ,весь интернет перерыл не могу понять как это сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В чем именно проблема?

Есть [несколько вариантов](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html) удалить запись из БД. Давайте рассмотрим простой пример:

```
@DeleteMapping("/delete")
public void deleteDocument(@RequestParam(value="id") Integer id){
    documentRepo.deleteById(id);
}
```

В данном случае удаляете запись по ее ID'шнику: `http://url/delete?id=123`.

Удалить запись можно так же, передав в тело запроса объект в виде JSON, если использовать метод `delete()`. Например:

```
@DeleteMapping("/delete")
public void deleteDocument(@RequestBody Document document){
    documentRepo.delete(document);
}
```

На этом варианты не заканчиваются, можете реализовывать методы, удаляющие данные и по другим входящим параметрам.

Comment: Спасибо большое ,проблема в том что я не мог сообразить как это сделать ))) , подскажите еще, как правильно повесить метод на кнопку "Удалить"  в шаблоне, в моем случае, заранее спасибо!

Comment: @МаксимШевченков лучше задайте новый вопрос, так как это уже реально вопрос, который стоит сделать отдельным для улучшения базы ответов сообщества. И в вопросе уточните, как удалять будете, `post` запросом передавая объект, или как-то иначе.